# "grep" a csv file including multi-lines fields?

Tags: shell, csv, grep, multiline

file.csv:

```
XA90;"standard"
XA100;"this is
the multi-line"
XA110;"other standard"
```

I want to grep the "XA100" entry like this:

```
grep XA100 file.csv
```

to obtain this result:

```
XA100;"this is
the multi-line"
```

but grep return only one line:

```
XA100;"this is
```

source.csv contains 3 entries.
The "XA100" entry contain a multi-line field.
And grep doesn't seem to be the right tool to "grep" CSV file including multilines fields.

Do you know the way to make the job ?

Edit: the real world file contains many columns. The researched term can be in any column (not at begin of line, nor at the begin of field). All fields are encapsulated by ". Any field can contain a multi-line, from 1 line to any, and this cannot be predicted.

Comment: how does your line starts with ? Always by X..... ?

Comment: No, but the real file I use allways start with " because *all* the fields are encapsuled by "

The real file contains many more columns. All columns can contain fields with multiples lines (2 or more).

Comment: `sed 's/^X/\n&/' |awk -v RS= '/multi-line/'`  replace `X` in `sed` commandwith the start of each line, it should work. But a fragil solution.

Comment: It works fine ! The small file.csv with sed 's/^X/\n&/' file.csv |awk -v RS= '/XA100/ {print}'

Comment: If you know the number of multi-lines the entry has, you can use grep options -A <num> or -B <num> which print lines of leading/trailing context after/before matching lines.

Comment: No, the number of multi-lines is various and undetermined (user input in a textarea html field).

Comment: In the real world file, each line start with ". So I replace X by " in the sed part and it's OK. Very nice, thank you !

Comment: " are replaced by "" in CSV file. But the first column is not concerned by " characters in my real world file. So sed part is OK.

Comment: Where did the real file come from? If it's MS-Excel then the newlines within the double quotes are just `\n`s while the newlines at the end of records are `\r\n`s - is that what you have?

Comment: Also if in the real world every field is surrounded by quotes, why would you post sample input here where that isn't the case? Please fix that and anything else that's different about your example vs your real input. And can your quoted fields contain double quotes and, if so are they escaped as `""` or `\"` or something else?

Comment: Not from Excel, generated by Pentaho. All fields are encapsulated by ". All " in fields are replaced by "". It could be hard to differentiate an entry beginning by ", and a line from a multi-lines field beginning with one or more ". sed part would have to count " characters... Luckily my CSV file is easier, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PS response, this works for the small example:

```
sed 's/^X/\n&/' file.csv | awk -v RS= '/XA100/ {print}'
```

For my real world CSV file, with many columns, with researched term anywhere, with unknown count of multi-lines, with characters " replaced by "", with multi-lines lines beginning with ", with all fields encapsulated by ", this works. Note the exclusion of the second character " in sed part:

```
sed 's/^"[^"]/\n&/' file.csv | awk -v RS= '/RESEARCH_TERM/ {print}'
```

Because first column of any entry cannot start with "". First column allways looks like "XXXXXXXXX", where X is any character but ".

Thank you all for so much responses, maybe others solutions are working depending the CSV file format you use.

Answer (score 1):

Give this line a try:

```
awk '/^XA100;/{p=1}p;p&&/"$/{p=0}' file
```

I extended your example a bit:

```
kent$  cat f
XA90;"standard"
XA100;"this is
the
multi-
line"
XA110;"other standard"

kent$  awk '/^XA100;/{p=1}p;p&&/"$/{p=0}' f
XA100;"this is
the
multi-
line"
```

Comment: That's neat and petite. I'll refrain from posting my buffering solution. ++

Comment: In general `XA100;` could be present at the start of a line inside a quoted field (`"...\nXA100;"`) and there could be an escaped quote before a newline inside a quoted field (`"foo""\nbar"`).

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you mention: *In the real world file, each line start with "*. I assume they also end with `"` and present you this:

Test file:

```
$ cat file
"single line"
"multi-
lined"
```

Code and outputs:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\"\n"} /single/' file
"single line"
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\"\n"} /m/' file
"multi-
lined"
```

You can also parametrize the search:

```
$ awk -v s="multi" 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\"\n"} match($0,s)' file
"multi-
lined"
```

Comment: In a typical CSV there could be a newline right at the start of a field (`"\nfoo"`) or after an escaped (double-quoted) quote (`"foo""\nbar"`) so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

try:
**Solution 1:**

```
awk -v RS="XA" 'NR==3{gsub(/$\n$/,"");print RS $0}'  Input_file
```

Making Record separator as string XA then looking for line 3rd here and then globally substituting the $\n$(which is to remove the extra line at the end of the line) with NULL. Then printing the Record Separator with the current line.

**Solution 2:**

```
awk '/XA100/{print;getline;while($0 !~ /^XA/){print;getline}}'  Input_file
```

Looking for string XA100 then printing the current line and using getline to go to next line, using while loop then which will run and print the lines until a line is starting from XA.

Comment: In general XA could exist inside a quoted field (`"foo XA bar"`). So could `XA100`. You should also mention the multi-char RS solution is gawk-specific and the getline solution has many caveats (see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline).

Comment: Apologies Ed, I didn't understand your pint here, could you please let me know more on same. Will be grateful to you.

Comment: A line of input might be `XA150;"like XA100 but better"` so anything trying to key off `XA` or `XA100` as the start or end of a record will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If this file was exported from MS-Excel or similar then lines end with `\r\n` while the newlines inside quotes are just `\n`s so then all you need is:

```
$ awk -v RS='\r\n' '/XA100/' file
XA100;"this is
the multi-line"
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS. On some platforms, e.g. cygwin, you'll have to add `-v BINMODE=3` so gawk sees the `\r`s rather than them getting stripped by underlying C primitives.

Otherwise, it's extremely hard to parse CSV files in general without a real CSV parser (which awk currently doesn't have but is in the works for GNU awk) but you could do this (again with GNU awk for multi-char RS):

```
$ cat file
XA90;"standard"
XA100;"this is
the multi-line"
XA110;"other standard"

$ awk -v RS="\"[^\"]*\"" -v ORS= '{gsub(/\n/," ",RT); print $0 RT}' file
XA90;"standard"
XA100;"this is the multi-line"
XA110;"other standard"
```

to replace all newlines within quotes with blank chars and then process it as regular 1-line-per-record file.